# g++ compilation error(fatal error) while running make command in terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile

I installed visual studio code in windows 10. I want to run my c++ program. I have a simple file: hello.cpp. i have created a make file

This is my c++ file:**hello.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Hello world "<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**:

```make
# Compiler settings - Can be customized.
CC = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall
LDFLAGS = 

# Makefile settings - Can be customized.
APPNAME = testing
EXT = .cpp
SRCDIR = /d/courseera/courses/testing
OBJDIR = obj

############## Do not change anything from here downwards! #############
SRC = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*$(EXT))
OBJ = $(SRC:$(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
DEP = $(OBJ:$(OBJDIR)/%.o=%.d)
# UNIX-based OS variables & settings
RM = rm
DELOBJ = $(OBJ)
# Windows OS variables & settings
DEL = del
EXE = .exe
WDELOBJ = $(SRC:$(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)=$(OBJDIR)\\%.o)

######################################################################## 
####################### Targets beginning here #########################
########################################################################

all: $(APPNAME)

# Builds the app
$(APPNAME): $(OBJ)
$(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# Creates the dependecy rules
%.d: $(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)
@$(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $< -MM -MT $(@:%.d=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) >$@

# Includes all .h files
-include $(DEP)
  
# Building rule for .o files and its .c/.cpp in combination with all .h
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)
$(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
 
################### Cleaning rules for Unix-based OS ###################
# Cleans complete project
.PHONY: clean
clean:
$(RM) $(DELOBJ) $(DEP) $(APPNAME)

# Cleans only all files with the extension .d
.PHONY: cleandep
cleandep:
$(RM) $(DEP)

#################### Cleaning rules for Windows OS #####################
# Cleans complete project
.PHONY: cleanw
cleanw:
$(DEL) $(WDELOBJ) $(DEP) $(APPNAME)$(EXE)

# Cleans only all files with the extension .d
.PHONY: cleandepw
cleandepw:
$(DEL) $(DEP)
```

When i give **make** command in my terminal i am getting an error like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o testing  
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'testing' failed
make: *** [testing] Error 1
```

Can anyone help me to sort out this error?(Hint: my file hello.cpp is inside the folder **testing**)

Comment: Do you really have a directory called "d"?

Comment: d is my local directory where i saved my file

Comment: Your makefile says that there's a directory called "d" in the root directory. Are you absolutely sure there is one?

Comment: D is my drive(local drive)

Comment: Then fix your makefile so it doesn't say that `d` is under the root directory.

Comment: Are you sure you have a directory `/d/courseera/courses/testing`? And there are some cpp files in there? Perhaps there's a spelling error in this path?  For example, `coursera`?

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain what the other commenters are getting at: the only way to get the output you see here given the makefile you show is if the `OBJ` variable is empty.  The only way `OBJ` can be empty is if `SRC` is empty.  The only way `SRC` can be empty is if the `wildcard` function expands to the empty string.  The only way the `wildcard` can expand to the empty string is if it doesn't match anything.  So, the question is why does your wildcard function not match anything?

There are two possibilities.  The first is that you have mistyped the path and it's just a typo.

The second is that, you appear to be using Windows and everything is difficult and annoying on Windows.  In particular, there are multiple different environments on Windows: there's the cygwin-style environment where POSIX-like paths are mapped to Windows-like paths (e.g., `/d/foo/bar` is mapped to `D:\foo\bar`).  There is a MinGW-style environment where Windows style paths are used but, to make things a bit simpler, you can use forward slashes instead of backslashes.  Then there's the full Windows cmd.com environment where you have to use backslashes.  Different of these need to be used in different places.

GNU make comes in two flavors on Windows: there's the cygwin version and the MinGW/Visual Studio version.  If you have the cygwin version you need to use POSIX-like paths.  If you have the MinGW/Visual Studio version you need to use Windows paths, but with forward slashes not backslashes.  So, if you have the MinGW/Visual Studio version of GNU make you should write:

```
SRCDIR = D:/courseera/courses/testing
```

(assuming that's the correct path).